# Is there a way to make 1,2 and 3 step ahead predictions with a gam model in R using the mgcv package?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, mgcv

I've got a quick question regarding using the `gam` function and the `predict.gam` function in R using the mgcv package. I've got a model built with two predictors and one response. However when I try to use the `predict.gam function` I'm not able to understand how I can make predictions using 1, 2 and 3 steps ahead. I've tried using arguments such as `n.ahead=2` however I always get the same result where I just get predicted values for my response. So if there are 100 response values, `predict.gam` gives me 100 prediction values. My base model is in the form of

```
mod2_AAR1<- gam(y~ s(x.1, bs="bs", k=21, m=c(3,2))+
                 s(x.2, bs="bs", k=21, m=c(3,2)), drop.intercept = FALSE,
    data=full_set_1)
```

Where x.1 and x.2 are 1st and 2nd time lags of y. However, I just want to know how can I make future predictions with this model n-steps ahead using `predict.gam`.

Thank you

Comment: You have to do it recursively, yourself; predict for the 1 step ahead using the covariate values of the last 2 observations as inputs for newdata. Get the predicted value and feed it back into predict with the last observation get the next prediction, repeat until you have the n stead ahead predictions you desire

Comment: Hi Gavin,
Thanks for the response. I have done this using an apply function and I am matching my results using the ```predict_rolling``` function from the "tsDyn." I'm able to get a 1 step ahead however when I try using it for 2 steps ahead there is a slight mismatch. It appears that there is an issue with the dimensions. I'll post the solution code if I'm able to resolve it.

Comment: it maybe possible to use predict()

The newdata in predict function needs to be a data.frame that contain the future x.1 and x2 values e.g. as.dataframe(x.1 =x.1.future.values, x.2 = x.2.future.values)